# How to decrease margin and padding of editText programmatically (android)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have `editText` which by default leaves lots of space. I added backgroud for textView, cause editText backgroud is not possible.

[image]

> When I execute command: `editText.setHeight(50);` of no matter what integer it gives me same result:

[image]

My text gets cropped. I think somehow I need to reduce editText margins to fit my text here.

> Main problem is that there is to much space between rows in first picture.

Comment: post your XML and related code

Comment: editText background is possible `mEditText.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);` or use a style `style="@style/EditTextStyleWhite"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
        int reducedValue =5;

        editText .setPadding(editText .getPaddingLeft()-reducedValue,
                editText .getPaddingTop()-reducedValue,
                editText .getPaddingRight()-reducedValue,
                editText .getPaddingBottom()-reducedValue);

        editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(editText .getPaddingLeft()-reducedValue,
                editText .getPaddingTop()-reducedValue,
                editText .getPaddingRight()-reducedValue,
                editText .getPaddingBottom()-reducedValue);
```

Comment: What that compoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds do ? Because with this command program crashes, but without it it's perfect.

Comment: ill add this because you can add space through this using drawable  look at this link ( This is Optional) https://www.codota.com/android/methods/android.widget.TextView/setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds 

But   setPadding also work fine you can try